# Android Studio Tutorial Missing app/src/main/res/layout/activity_my.xml

Tags: android, android-studio

According to the Android Studio first app tutorial, there should be a folder in the res called layout folder and inside that folder  > activity_my.xml file.

My res folder does not contain the layout folder, it has drawable, mipmap, and value folders.

I have attempted restarting the program and creating multiple new projects.

Comment: Try looking in res/layout - where the project default layout file will be called activity_main.xml

Comment: I have updated my question. I am in fact missing the layout folder within the res folder.

Comment: You can try to add new Activity from context menu, I think the layout folder will be create automatically

Comment: @HuyN how do I access the context menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on resource  folder and create new directory with layout name and put your xml  in it . i hope your problem solved .

Right click on res  folder and create new directory with layout name and put ur XML in it . hope ur problem solved .

Comment: I tried this. it automatically creates a folder in the drawable folder within res instead of creating a folder in res.

Comment: when doing this it created: res > drawable > layout

Answer (score 2):

The Android Studio tutorial incorrectly states that you should open a new "Empty Activity" template, however the instructions match better with the "Empty Views Activity" template as that comes out of box with the later described file (App > res > layout > activity_main.xml)

I know this is an old post, but its the first thing that comes up when looking to solve this particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create in drawable folder , create in res  folder or another way is to cut your layout directory and paste in res folder